Laravel sail can't access api routes
I can connect to the mysql database but when I surf to localhost:14 i get a error that he can not connect.
I get the google chrome error page with the messsage:
This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I've created a new laravel app using sail with this command:
curl -s "https://laravel.build/app-name" | bash && cd app-name && ./vendor/bin/sail up
.env:
APP_PORT=14

this is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.3/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-81}:81'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local

My route is setup correctly
(base) ➜  app-name ./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:list

  GET|HEAD       / ....
  GET|HEAD       api/goods ..... goods.index › GoodsController@index
  GET|HEAD       up ..............

api.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\RecipeController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/goods', [GoodsController::class, 'index'])->name('goods.index');

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
}

app.php
    'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ])->toArray(),


Is Vite running? any error in laravel.log? Debug mode turned on? Environment = local? Use xdebug and try to debugm try to find and read the nginx error logs
